# Text inside cardview not getting displayed

Tags: android, android-cardview

Only images are displayed in cardview.How to show textview also.I want to display hardcoded text below respective images.Here is xml file for layout.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jkeS.png).This is the final required layout,but i am only able to achieve this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agfhJ.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.gcg.justtry.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
 tools:context="com.example.gcg.justtry.MainActivity">

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
  android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"

        >

        <RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:contentDescription="Computer Society"
                android:id="@+id/csy"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/cs" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/csy"
                android:text="Computer Society"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"/>


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card1"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/card">

        <RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/micro"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/mtts" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/micro"
                android:text="MTT-S"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card2"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/card1">

        <RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/power"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/pes" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/power"
                android:text="PES"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card3"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"


        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/card2">

        <RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/women"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/wie" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/women"
                android:text="WIE"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"/>


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Try to set the textcolor to black, maybe it is setted to white and you cant see it

Comment: @Prashant Chamoli check my answer and let me know

Comment: @MartinDeSimone already did that but still stuck.

Comment: @ArpitPatel it worked, thanks. But what was wrong in my code.

Comment: Image cover the whole space of the cardview  so thats why textview doesn't show.

Comment: @ArpitPatel what is the use of this line:       android:weightSum="4"

Comment: that means you divide into four part of the layout. and after that weight give to other components so they can cover that space.

Comment: hope you understand.

Comment: Yup. Thanks a lot @ArpitPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code and change android:src attribute accordingly.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/csy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:contentDescription="Computer Society"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/csy"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="Computer Society"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/micro"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_mtt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/micro"
                android:text="MTT-S" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/power"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_pes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/power"
                android:text="PES" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/women"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="90dp"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_wie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/women"
                android:text="WIE" />


        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

See Image here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the height of card view,you are not providing enough space for the textview to appear ,add warp_content as the cardview height

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card1"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/card">
```

This would be fine ,I guess...

Set text color for TextView..Just i case

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/power"
   android:text="PES"
   android:textcolor="@color/blue"
   android:paddingStart="10dp"/>
```